# Nuxt dynamic route population using graphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, nuxt.js

In nuxtconfig.js you can use 
generate: { routes() {} }

to return all the dynamic routes for your app.

All the examples use axios ie:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  generate: {
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get('https://my-api/users')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data.map((user) => {
          return {
            route: '/users/' + user.id,
            payload: user
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

How can i do this with graphQL / apollo?

I have tried this and some other combinations...

```
let v
  apollo: {
    posts: {
      query: gql`
        query posts {
          posts {
            title
          }
        }
      `,
      result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
        v = data
      }
    }
  },

  generate: {
    subFolders: true,
    routes: function() {
      return {
        route: '/posts/' + v.title,
        payload: v
      }
    }
  },
```

The error is that i dont think apollo is able to be used in nuxtconfig?

This also doesnt work

```
  generate: {
    routes: function() {
      apollo: {
        posts: {
         query:`query posts {
           posts {
            title
          }
        }
      `,
      result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
       return {
        route: '/posts/' + data.title,
        payload: data
       }
      }
    }
  },

    }
  },
```

Comment: What's probably happening here is that the Apollo module is not initialized during build time, so ```v``` is never filled.  You'll instead need to make the GraphQL query from inside the ```routes``` function instead.

Comment: Ive tried that also, putting the apollo query in the routes function. Seems like apollo does not run in nuxtconfig every way i've tried. I ended up just hitting the grapql api with Axios heh.